# Classic ASP with Oracle

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I have a select statement which is running fine in sqlplus but when i m trying to run in Classic ASP code I am getting below error

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month

My Select Query is as below

SELECT YEAR_MONTH, LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_DATE('201106','YYYYMM'),'MM/DD/YYYY')) AS MAX_END_DT FROM MONTH_DIM WHERE '04-28-2016' BETWEEN MONTH_START_DATE AND MONTH_END_DATE

ASP Code as Below
Dim rs
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText =  "SELECT YEAR_MONTH, LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(TO_DATE('" & MAXYEARMONTH & "','YYYYMM'),'MM/DD/YYYY')) AS MAX_END_DT FROM MONTH_DIM WHERE '" &  END_DT & "' BETWEEN MONTH_START_DATE AND MONTH_END_DATE"
    set rs = cmd.execute --here is problem
```

Comment: is it something to do with NLS_DATE_FORMAT? I have checked in SQLPlus it show MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: What is the format for  END_DT? Better use TO_DATE with your format fro END_DT.

Comment: And one TO_DATE is enough. LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('" & MAXYEARMONTH & "','YYYYMM'))

Comment: @Mottor, thank you for pointing out i have changed from MM-DD-YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY but with same error

Comment: And "Classic ASP with Oracle" is not a good title. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you tell me what comes in MAXYEARMONTH  and END_DT in runtime?

Comment: Please find the below query
SELECT YEAR_MONTH, LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('201106','YYYYMM')) AS MAX_END_DT FROM MONTH_DIM WHERE '04/28/2016' BETWEEN MONTH_START_DATE AND MONTH_END_DATE

Comment: whats the data type for month_start_date and month_end_date

Comment: data type format in oracle table is "Date"

Comment: use TO_DATE('" & END_DT & "','MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: @Mottor, Bingo.. :)
Thank you...I will mark answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use TO_DATE('" &  END_DT & "','MM/DD/YYYY')